# C++ Inheritance pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, virtual

my problem is: How do I implement pure virtual functions in an inherited class? It always says i didn't implement the only function, but I tried to do it. So where is my mistake?

My code:

A.h:

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    virtual std::pair<A*, A*> f1(const A& o) const=0;
    virtual ~A();
};
```

B.h:

```
#include "A.h"

class B : public A {
public:
B();
virtual ~B();
virtual std::pair<A*, A*> f1(const A& o);
};
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"

B::B() : A() {}
B::~B() {}
std::pair<A*, A*> B::f1(const A& o) {
   A* K1=new B();
   A* K2=new B();
   return std::make_pair (K1, K2);
}
```

I get following error:

```
B.cpp: In member function ‘virtual std::pair<A*, A*> B::f1(const A&)’:
B.cpp:14:16: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘B’
    A* K1=new B();
                ^
In file included from B.cpp:1:0:
B.h:4:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘B’:
 class B : public A {
       ^
In file included from B.h:1:0,
                 from B.cpp:1:
A.h:10:28: note:    virtual std::pair<A*, A*> A::f1(const A&) const
  virtual std::pair<A*, A*> f1(const A& o) const=0;
                            ^
B.cpp:15:16: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘B’
    A* K2=new B();
                ^
In file included from B.cpp:1:0:
B.h:4:7: note:   since type ‘B’ has pure virtual functions
 class B : public A {
       ^
```

Also: What is correct, A* K1=new A(); or new B(); ?

Comment: `A::f1` is a `const` method. You forgot the `const` at the end of the method in class `B`.

Comment: That's why `override` keyword is awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets' put those two side by side and look closer:

```
A: virtual std::pair<A*, A*> f1(const A& o) const=0; 
B: virtual std::pair<A*, A*> f1(const A& o);
```

Well, I see a difference, one of these is a `const` function, and the other is not.  That makes them two different functions.  Since the `const` function was never overloaded, `B` is still abstract, like `A`, and cannot be instantiated.

```
A* K1 = new A(); //would give you an A, if A weren't abstract.  Do you want an A or B?
A* K1 = new B(); //gives a B object, stored as a pointer to an A interface.
```

I also highly recommend using `std::unique_ptr` where you currently have owning raw pointers.  They'll prevent headaches later.

Answer (score 2):

Your override has to match in cv-qualification. You're missing a `const` here:

```
std::pair<A*, A*> B::f1(const A& o) /* [const] */
```

Since it doesn't override and your base class method is pure virtual, your derived class becomes abstract. You can't instantiate objects of abstract type.

You have to add `const` to both the declaration and definition. Also, to make sure it overrides, use the keyword `override`:

```
std::pair<A*, A*> f1(const A& o) override; // error since it does not override
```

Answer (score 2):

In B, your function needs to be `virtual std::pair<A*, A*> f1(const A&) const;` or it's a different function, not overriding the one from A.

(If you're using a C++11 compiler, do `std::pair<A*, A*> f1(const A&) const override;` and it becomes clear to the reader that you intended to override the function.)